# Python how to calculate average of range list?

Tags: python-3.x, average

Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

I am gotting error  Vidurkis = sum(B)/len(B)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

```
A = int(input('Betkoks skaicius'))

if A == 0:
    print('Ačiū')
if A <= 10 and A>=-10: 
    if A<0:
        print('Neigiamas vienženklis')
    if A>0:
        print('Teigiamas vienženklis')

else:
     print('| {:^20} |'.format('Autorius: '))
for r in range(10,A,1):

    Vidurkis = sum(r)/len(r)
    print(Vidurkis)
```

Answer (score 2):

after

```
sum = 0
```

`sum` is no longer the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function! You would have to rename that variable. The real error is, however, that you are applying functions that take iterables as arguments to integers (Your loop variable `B` is an `int` while `sum` and `len` would expect a `list` or similar). The following would suffice:

```
r = range(10, A, 1)  # == range(10, A)
Vidurkis = sum(r)/len(r)  # only works for A > 10, otherwise ZeroDivisionError
```

Comment: I want to calculate the value between 10 and the arithmetic mean of the entered number. I am gotting the same error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Did you remove the `sum = 0` line and the entire for loop? So you want the arithmetic mean of 10 and the given number? Isn't `(10 + A) / 2` a less wasteful formula then `r = range(10, A+1); sum(r)/len(r)`?

Comment: Yes, I do, I have typed in accidentally.  I want to do like this if I enter 15, it sums all numbers 11+12+13+14+15 and divides from 5

Comment: That's what I mean: `(11+12+13+14+15)/5` is the same as `(11+15)/2`. That particular range you'd be looking for is `range(11, A+1)`.

Comment: But I have to calculate how much numbers are in the list. I don't know from what number I have to divide.  len() funkction doesn't work for me. TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: Thanks I got it.